# Modify the folder name but it is not updated in Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I coding in Visual Studio Code

I changed the folder name 'Global' to lowercase 'global' [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOxgg.png)

But.. It is not updated  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjeJI.png)

And, I get the error message [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUDUi.png)

What's wrong with it? How can I fix it?

Comment: It might be due to that your changes was not saved. By default vs code autosaves the changes, in case your auto save is not enabled then please manually enabled it by going to `File` and click the `Auto Save`.

Comment: Maybe because in Windows, file and directory names are case insensitive so your changing `Global` to `global` does not mean anything in Windows?

Comment: @ChinkySight I'm sure i've saved it. I also tried to close and restart vs code, but an error still occurred.

Comment: @RoslanAmir  It in Mac OS.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried using 'globals' and it seemed to solve the problem. I think 'global' may be a reserved word.